# empty space when dragging it

Tags: sass

I have a simple custom splitter that works great. However, I have a little issue:

The **first time** I drag the splitter down it adds an **empty space**, after that I can drag with it with no problem (up or down). Can anyone tell me what may be causing the extra space issue? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's the code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-resizable-wkxfku?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
 onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {

if (!this.grabber) {
  return;
}

this.resizer(event.clientY - this.oldY);
this.oldY = event.clientY;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should consider using `clientHeight` instead of `offsetHeight` because  CSS height is [calculated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) as clientHeight minus CSS paddings* while `offsetHeight` also includes borders height

```
clientHeight = content height + paddings

offsetHeight = clientHeight + borders height
```

Now you have two options

1) Use `clientHeight` together with `box-sizing: border-box;` (paddings will be included in css height)

**ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.height = parseInt(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.clientHeight);
}
```

**css**

```
.textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-resizable-6kekym?file=app/app.component.ts)**

2) Use content height

```
ngOnInit() {
  const elem = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
  const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(elem);
  const paddingsHeight = parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingTop)
                                          + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingBottom)
  this.height = parseFloat(elem.clientHeight) - paddingsHeight;
}
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-resizable-u1nf8b?file=app/app.component.ts)**